# Trying to set up multi-locale Chapel on a Raspberry Pi cluster

Tags: raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, chapel

I am wondering if anyone could provide me with guidance on how to set up multi-locale on a cluster of Raspberry Pi -- a procedure or walk through or even just hints would be welcome.

Chapel compiles successfully on a single node and I can run all the tutorial code. I re-made chapel with the suggested environment variables in place for multi-locale but I just can't get it to work.

The output from `printenv` looks like this:

```
CHPL_HOME: /home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0 *
script location: /home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/util/chplenv
CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM: linux64
CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER: gnu
CHPL_TARGET_ARCH: aarch64
CHPL_TARGET_CPU: aarch64 *
CHPL_LOCALE_MODEL: flat
CHPL_COMM: gasnet *
CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE: udp *
CHPL_GASNET_SEGMENT: everything
CHPL_TASKS: qthreads
CHPL_LAUNCHER: amudprun
CHPL_TIMERS: generic
CHPL_UNWIND: none
CHPL_MEM: jemalloc
CHPL_ATOMICS: cstdlib
CHPL_NETWORK_ATOMICS: none
CHPL_GMP: gmp
CHPL_HWLOC: hwloc
CHPL_REGEXP: re2
CHPL_LLVM: none
CHPL_AUX_FILESYS: none
```

My environment variables look like this:

```
CHPL_HOME=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0
CHPL_TARGET_CPU=aarch64
CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=udp
CHPL_COMM=gasnet
GASNET_WORKERIP=192.168.1.0
GASNET_SPAWNFN=S
GASNET_SSH_CMD=ssh
GASNET_SSH_OPTIONS=-o LogLevel=Error -x
GASNET_SSH_SERVERS=oc2-a oc2-b
GASNET_MASTERIP=192.168.1.146
```

Using this example code:

```
use Memory;
for loc in Locales do
  on loc {
    writeln("locale #", here.id, "...");
    writeln("  ...is named: ", here.name);
    writeln("  ...has ", here.numPUs(), " processor cores");
    writeln("  ...has ", here.physicalMemory(unit=MemUnits.GB, retType=real), " GB of memory");
    writeln("  ...has ", here.maxTaskPar, " maximum parallelism");
  }
```

And compiling it like this:

```
chpl --no-local -o printLocales printLocales.chpl
```

When I run the executable:

```
./printLocales -nl 2
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: line 1: 22782 Illegal instruction     env 'AMUDP_SLAVE_ARGS=1,192,168,1,146,159,52,192.168.1.0' '/home/mpiu/Code/chapel/printLocales_real' '-nl' '1' '-E' 'SHELL=/bin/bash' '-E' 'GASNET_WORKERIP=192.168.1.0' '-E' 'CHPL_HOME=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0' '-E' 'CHPL_TARGET_CPU=aarch64' '-E' 'GASNET_SPAWNFN=S' '-E' 'PWD=/home/mpiu/Code/chapel' '-E' 'LOGNAME=mpiu' '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty' '-E' 'MANPATH=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/man:' '-E' 'HOME=/home/mpiu' '-E' 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_CMD=ssh' '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_OPTIONS=-o LogLevel=Error -x' '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_SERVERS=oc2-a oc2-b' '-E' 'CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=udp' '-E' 'SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.47 53342 192.168.1.146 22' '-E' 'GASNET_MASTERIP=192.168.1.146' '-E' 'CHPL_COMM=gasnet' '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user' '-E' 'TERM=xterm-256color' '-E' 'USER=mpiu' '-E' 'SHLVL=1' '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_ID=c3' '-E' 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1002' '-E' 'SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.47 53342 22' '-E' 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' '-E' 'PATH=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/bin/linux64-aarch64:/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/util:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games' '-E' 'MAIL=/var/mail/mpiu' '-E' 'SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0' '-E' 'OLDPWD=/home/mpiu' '-E' '_=./printLocales'
```

I have tried many different things (including using the MPI conduit as well), I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. If it matters, MPI works fine on this cluster.

---

<sub>*( An original error one-liner slightly re-formatted for faster readability )*</sub>

```
bash: line 1: 22782 Illegal instruction \
      env \
      'AMUDP_SLAVE_ARGS=1,192,168,1,146,159,52,192.168.1.0' \
      '/home/mpiu/Code/chapel/printLocales_real' \
      '-nl' '1' \
      '-E' 'SHELL=/bin/bash' \
      '-E' 'GASNET_WORKERIP=192.168.1.0' \
      '-E' 'CHPL_HOME=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0' \
      '-E' 'CHPL_TARGET_CPU=aarch64' \
      '-E' 'GASNET_SPAWNFN=S' \
      '-E' 'PWD=/home/mpiu/Code/chapel' \
      '-E' 'LOGNAME=mpiu' \
      '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty' \
      '-E' 'MANPATH=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/man:' \
      '-E' 'HOME=/home/mpiu' \
      '-E' 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' \
      '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_CMD=ssh' \
      '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_OPTIONS=-o LogLevel=Error -x' \
      '-E' 'GASNET_SSH_SERVERS=oc2-a oc2-b' \
      '-E' 'CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=udp' \
      '-E' 'SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.47 53342 192.168.1.146 22' \
      '-E' 'GASNET_MASTERIP=192.168.1.146' \
      '-E' 'CHPL_COMM=gasnet' \
      '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user' \
      '-E' 'TERM=xterm-256color' \
      '-E' 'USER=mpiu' \
      '-E' 'SHLVL=1' \
      '-E' 'XDG_SESSION_ID=c3' \
      '-E' 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1002' \
      '-E' 'SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.47 53342 22' \
      '-E' 'LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' \
      '-E' 'PATH=/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/bin/linux64-aarch64:/home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0/util:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games' \
      '-E' 'MAIL=/var/mail/mpiu' \
      '-E' 'SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0' \
      '-E' 'OLDPWD=/home/mpiu' \
      '-E' '_=./printLocales'
```

Comment: Hello @Theodore, thank you for your interest in Chapel. `Illegal instruction` tells me that the compiled binary contains some instruction that the CPU does not recognize. What happens if you unset the `CHPL_TARGET_CPU` variable?

Comment: Reference: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/usingchapel/chplenv.html#chpl-target-arch

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your settings. In `chpl --no-local -o printLocales printLocales.chpl` you shouldn't need `--no-local` (and in fact it will cause worse performance).

Are you running `make` and the `chpl` compilation on the same node type you are trying to execute on? Does the `GASNET_SPAWNFN=L` setting (described in https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/platforms/udp.html ) allow it to work?

Comment: I'd be curious to see the output of a `./printLocales -nl 2 --verbose` run, but tend to think that @Vass is on the right track:  `illegal instruction` suggests to me that the back-end C compiler has generated a binary that isn't appropriate for the CPUs on which it's being run for some reason.

Comment: BTW, regarding @mppf's comment above: setting CHPL_COMM=gasnet automatically causes the compiler to use the `--no-local` flag.  For that reason, he's correct that you shouldn't need `--no-local` (because it's already the default for your settings), but incorrect that it will cause worse performance for your run (because it's required for any multi-locale run to work correctly).

Comment: I have discovered that the Illegal instruction is coming from the printLocales_real executable (the -v output is helpful and allowed me to try different executions manually). When I set GASNET_SPAWNFN=L, nothing comes out of the programs at all. When I run it like this, ./printLocales_real 2 oc2-a oc2-b, I get output that seems reasonable, just no output from the program itself. With GASNET_SPAWNFN=S, the logging seems correct for running on the two nodes, but the printLocales_real produces the illegal instruction error. What is in the _real program? How is it generated?

Comment: Hi @Theodore, the `_real` program is the executable that runs on each locale. `printLocales` without "_real" is only a thin launcher that fires up printLocales_real on each Pi. The context is here: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/usingchapel/multilocale.html

Comment: P.S. Both printLocales and printLocales_real are produced by the Chapel compiler. Under the covers, the binary code is produced by gcc, based on your CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER.

Comment: @TheodoreSwoyer: Thanks for the additional information.  It might be useful to bring this over to our GitHub issues page at https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues where it'd probably be easier to debug this than it is in the SO comments section.  Specifically, I'd be curious to know (a) what CPU type is performing the compilation and (b) what the output of adding the `--print-commands` flag to your compilation line shows in order to (c) determine what CPU type the _real binary is being generated for and why illegal instructions may be getting generated.

Comment: @Brad: thanks for the feedback. Working on this some more, I think my problem was the CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM: linux64 env variable; I believe that this may have prompted the compiler to generate something other than an aarch64 executable. When I changed that to aarch64, and attempted to re-make chapel, the qthreads software no longer compiles and the errors abort the make. I will look at this again and post on the github page if that is in fact what is happening. Again, appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @TheodoreSwoyer: Thanks for that observation.  I have to admit that I seem to be unclear about the current impacts of setting the *PLATFORM variable to `aarch64` vs. the *CPU variable (and don't know that I have easy access to an ARM platform to experiment on at the moment).  I'll check with the rest of the team and see what more I can learn, but would definitely be interested in seeing a log of the make errors you're getting on a GitHub issue if you have the time / interest to capture them there.

Comment: @TheodoreSwoyer: Oh wait, I'm having a belated "aha" moment.  Would you try (0) reverting CHPL_HOST_PLATFORM and CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM to linux64, (1) setting CHPL_HOST_ARCH=aarch64 (assuming you're compiling and launching from an arm processor); (2) typing `[g]make` again from $CHPL_HOME to rebuild, (3) re-compiling and running your program?  I'd been assuming all along that the illegal instruction was coming from the `_real` binary, but am realizing now that it's likely coming from the launcher binary.  If this doesn't work, I'd be curious to see the result of `printchplenv --all`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Even with that getting illegal instruction. The printchplenv --all looks like this:
machine info: Linux oc2-a 3.16.85+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 30 19:02:35 CEST 2020 aarch64
CHPL_HOME: /home/mpiu/chapel/chapel-1.23.0 *
CHPL_HOST_PLATFORM: linux64 *
CHPL_HOST_COMPILER: gnu
CHPL_HOST_ARCH: aarch64
CHPL_TARGET_PLATFORM: linux64
CHPL_TARGET_COMPILER: gnu
CHPL_TARGET_ARCH: native *
CHPL_TARGET_CPU: native
CHPL_LOCALE_MODEL: flat
CHPL_COMM: gasnet *
  CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE: udp *
  CHPL_GASNET_SEGMENT: everything
CHPL_TASKS: fifo *
CHPL_LAUNCHER: amudprun

Comment: I have tried many other permutations of the HOST, TARGET and ARCH settings. Sometimes the _real file does not get generated and sometimes the make fails. When I specify GASNET_SPAWNFN=L I get nothing out from any example program. with 'S' for that variabale, I get the illegal instruction. Someone has it working, https://chapel-lang.org/CHIUW/2015/talks/CHIUW-Chapel_on_ARM_final.pdf, so I must just be doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Time for a GitHub issue I think, both to make things like the printchplenv dump above readable, and so that I get notifications when you comment, where currently I'm relying on remembering to check a browser tab every few days.  :)  We've definitely run on arm before (a bunch at times), my sense is that we're just missing something simple.

Comment: I don't recall any further information beyond what's here, but I'm forgetting something, let me know, @theodore-swoyer.  I know people have successfully run Chapel on Raspberry Pi clusters, but wasn't able to debug the issue well based on the comments exchange here, which is why I was suggesting taking it to a GitHub issue on our repo.

Comment: Thank you @Brad for your kind update. Given the last sentence, about successful multi-locale Chapel on RPi-cluster(s)  - is there any such initiative documented, in any form or fashion, as a "setup guide" for a re-usable master plan to help spawn more Chapel clusters? Wishing your new Chapel Team all the best in driving this great Project forwards